# need help resetting the bios password

Tags: bios, eeprom

the laptop set a password on itself, and the backdoor passwords don't do anything, passwords generated by my hint numbers are incorrect (I generate them on bios-pw.org).

I salvaged this laptop from a school because it worked great and there was no reason to throw it out, there is nothing wrong with it and I have reinstalled the os in the past (aka. the bios didn't have the password in the past but decided to invite itself inside the laptop)

Its manufacturer is intel and name is intel powered classmate pc
its version is clamshell

I have already tried removing the cmos battery but that didn't work, I read somewhere that shorting the eeprom would reset it but I dont know where it is and how to short it

I just found out the bios info, I will copy paste it here as it is spelled in unicode characters

---

```
      SPCDV10L.86.A.0047.2013.0410.1210 
      ================================
          PHOENIX SC-T 2009-2011
```

---

512 KB L2 Cache

System BIOS shadowed

Video BIOS shadowed

BIOS Version:1.05ALG_S

EC Version: 1.02

The OS boots.

[image: password prompt]

Comment: also, I tried cmospwd in the past, didnt work, had a error dont remember what it was

Comment: Do you mean the CMOS battery?

Comment: no, I tried removing the cmos in the past and didnt work, then i left it removed for a month  and still didnt work

Comment: Are there any dip switches or headers on the motherboard, near the BIOS?

Comment: uhh, I dont know where the bios is, I dont know much about it i just want my boot options back

Comment: Please [edit] the question and improve it. (1) You don't necessarily want to "short the eeprom", you want to regain *access*, right? (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). Access to what? "I just want my boot options back" may mean "to BIOS/UEFI settings", "to boot menu" or even "to any installed OS". Does any OS boot? (2) Specify the exact model of the laptop and BIOS/UEFI version (if possible).

Comment: (3) "It set a password on itself" suggests this happened without your consent. This is alarming by itself, but also means that *maybe* you don't now what kind of password this is exactly. One can set a password for BIOS, HDD, encrypted filesystem or whatever really. Since it's not clear (yet) what access you want to regain, we shouldn't make assumptions. Take a photo of the screen where you're asked for the password and add to the question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski os boots, and ill send the photo right away

Comment: https://ibb.co/4KYw0fG

Comment: Comments are not for adding relevant information. The question body is. Please specify the exact model of the laptop and BIOS/UEFI version (if possible), but this time [edit] the question instead of posting in comments.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice

Comment: bios version is impossible to get, ill find out the model of the laptop and add it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121312/discussion-between-rng-and-kamil-maciorowski).

Comment: We need the make and model of laptop please

Comment: @Moab the computer doesnt display it

Comment: under it is not much info

Comment: its just a office activation code

Comment: OH SHIT, MASSIVE BREAKTHROUGH, I FOUND OUT THE BIOS INFO

Comment: Brand should be on the outside of the laptop?

Comment: read the original question, its a intel powered classmate pc, its made for schools (normal pc but with custom boot splash screen and custom casing)